# Index was outside the bounds of the array SqlDataReader.GetDecimal

Tags: c#, .net, sql-server

I want to sum up my `Amount` column, but I receive this error message

> Additional information: Index was outside the bounds of the array.

Here is the definition of the Balance table from SQL database:

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[Balance]
(
    [BalanceID] [int] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
    [Sn] [nvarchar](50) NULL,
    [Description] [nvarchar](1000) NULL,
    [Date] [date] NULL,
    [Amount] [decimal](8, 0) NULL
)
```

Here is the code C# that accesses the table via SQL inline

```
cn.Open();

SqlCommand cmd = cn.CreateCommand();
cmd.CommandType = CommandType.Text;
cmd.CommandText = "Select sum(Amount) from Balance where Sn=@sn and Date Between @SD and @ED";

cmd.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@sn", txtSn.Text));
cmd.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@SD", DTPStart.Text));
cmd.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@ED", DTPEnd.Text));
SqlDataReader reader = cmd.ExecuteReader();

while (reader.Read())
{
    Debt = reader.GetDecimal(4);
}

reader.Close();
cn.Close();
```

Any help will be much appreciated!

Comment: where do you get the error?

Comment: If you only want a single value, why not use ExecuteScalar ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Method [GetDecimal](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqldatareader.getdecimal(v=vs.110).aspx) gets the value of column having zero-based index provided as argument of method call.

You're returning only one column in your query `Select sum(Amount) from Balance`, but trying to achieve fifth column in `reader.GetDecimal(4)`

So change your code to

```
Debt = reader.GetDecimal(0);
```

**Update**: As it was noted in comments - in your particular case you don't need `ExecuteReader` at all. Since you're returning single value from server - you can use [ExecuteScalar](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqlcommand.executescalar(v=vs.110).aspx) instead, which executes the query, and returns the first column of the first row in the result set returned by the query.